# Why Array temp is different than temp.slice()?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple code here:

```
n=3;k=1

var combine = function(n, k) {
    let res = [];
    helper(1, []);
    function helper (start, temp) {
        if (temp.length === k) {
            console.log(1, temp);
            console.log(2, temp.slice());
            res.push(temp.slice());
            return;
        }        
        for (let i = start; i<=n; i++) {
            temp.push(i);
            helper(i+1, temp);
            temp.pop();
        } 
    }
    return res;
};

combine(n,k);
```

My question is, in console log, I see temp is exactly the same as temp.slice().
But `res.push(temp)` is different than `res.push(temp.slice())`

`res.push(temp)` push empty array to res. `res.push(temp.slice())` push the correct values. Below is the console log and output.

```
1 [ 1 ]
2 [ 1 ]
1 [ 2 ]
2 [ 2 ]
1 [ 3 ]
2 [ 3 ]
[ [ 1 ], [ 2 ], [ 3 ] ]

1 [ 1 ]
2 [ 1 ]
1 [ 2 ]
2 [ 2 ]
1 [ 3 ]
2 [ 3 ]
[ [], [], [] ]
```

Anyone please can tell me what is wrong here? I just simply want to push [1], [2], [3] into array.

Comment: The slice method does a shallow clone of the original. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: Simply push [1], [2], [3] into a new array. Why the original array, aka res.push(temp) give me empty array, but the shallow array, aka res.push(temp.slice()) works fine?

Comment: where the values `[ [ 1 ], [ 2 ], [ 3 ] ]` or `[ [], [], [] ]` came from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the case when n=1 and k=1. Your function will be equivalent to:

```
let res = [];
let temp = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
    temp.push(i);
    if (temp.length === 1) {
       res.push(temp.slice());
       // wrong: res.push(temp);
    }
    temp.pop();
}
```

When you are pushing `temp` to `res`, you are pushing a reference to it. When you call `temp.pop()`, that array inside of `res` will also be modified. When you use `temp.slice`, you are creating a one-level deep clone of `temp`, which allows you to call pop on `temp` without modifying that clone.